# Is there a way to manage development of Azure Data Factory using GIT Flow?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory, git-flow

Is there a way to manage an azure data factory dev environment with azure DevOps Git integration with GitFlow branching model like https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/
Especially how to deal with hot fixes??

Answer (score 1):

If you're writing explicitly versioned software or need to support many versions of your product in the field, git-flow is the way to go.

At this point we could see an Azure Repos Git organization can have numerous repositories, but each repository can only relate to one data factory hence, you cannot maintain multiple versions of ADF in single repository or branch.

If your intention is to maintain multiple versions of ADF on single repo/ master branch using GIT flow, then it is not yet possible. [Source control - Azure Data Factory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/source-control#author-with-azure-repos-git-integration)

Comment: I agree with you as I too have same understanding that it is not yet possible. May I ask if there is any way around for this.. if not how should I manage hotfixes..as I cannot find any Microsoft standard documentation for that as well..

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation, sure I will try my best to fetch you a workaround to it.